# Searching a Hash

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to complete this Codewars Challenge and I'm confused as to where I'm going wrong. Could someone please give me a hand?

The [question](https://www.codewars.com/kata/577ff15ad648a14b780000e7/train/ruby) provides a "database" of translations for `Welcome`, and the instructions say:

> - Think of a way to store the languages as a database (eg an object). The languages are listed below so you can copy and paste!
> - Write a 'welcome' function that takes a parameter 'language' (always a string), and returns a greeting - if you have it in your database. It should default to English if the language is not in the database, or in the event of an invalid input.

My attempt:

```
def greet(language)
  
  greeting = {  'english'=>'Welcome',
    'czech'=>'Vitejte',
    'danish'=>'Velkomst',
    'dutch'=>'Welkom',
    'estonian'=>'Tere tulemast',
    'finnish'=>'Tervetuloa',
    'flemish'=>'Welgekomen',
    'french'=>'Bienvenue',
    'german'=>'Willkommen',
    'irish'=>'Failte',
    'italian'=>'Benvenuto',
    'latvian'=>'Gaidits',
    'lithuanian'=>'Laukiamas',
    'polish'=>'Witamy',
    'spanish'=>'Bienvenido',
    'swedish'=>'Valkommen',
    'welsh'=>'Croeso'
  }

    greeting.key?(language) ? greeting.each { |k, v| return v if language == k } : 'IP_ADDRESS_INVALID'

end
```

To my eyes when I run my code through the IDE it seems to be working as per request but I guess I must be wrong somehow.

It's telling me it :

> Expected: "Laukiamas", instead got: "Welcome"

But when I type:

```
 p greet("lithuanian")
```

I get `Laukiamas`.

Comment: First, it looks like you have not understood the instructions; you are _never_ supposed to return `IP_ADDRESS_INVALID` (that's an input, not an output). Look more closely at the sample tests in order to understand what's supposed to happen. — Second, you need to make up your mind: are you going to use this hash as a hash (doing direct lookup by key) or as an array (cycling through all the pairs)? It makes no sense to do both! (Sorry to be rather vague, but if I said any more I'd be writing your code for you.)

Comment: Hint you can return a value for a key, for example, like this: `greeting[language]`. No need to iterate the whole hash...

Comment: Tip: Don't declare static look-up tables in a method, make a constant like `GREETINGS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide you `greeting` hash with a default value. It is as simple as

```
greeting.default = "Welcome"
```

This enhanced hash does all the work for you. Just look up the key; when it is not there you'll get "Welcome".

Comment: For education sake this is the\a better answer . The default state is clear thus explicitly addressing the specific problem requirement; code structure, what a concept! NEXT encourage the OP to review Hash ruby documentation. FINALLY I would beat our intrepid OP over the IDE with ALL CAPS admonitions about not addressing string land mines - casing, nil, otherStuff?  It is the coder's responsibility to cover "derived requirements", things that must be addressed due to the nature of the programming language.

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

First of all, please don't post *links* to exercises or homework questions. Quote them in your original question to avoid link rot or additional create work for people trying to help you out.

### Understanding the Problem Defined by the Linked Question

Secondly, you're misunderstanding the core question. The requirement is basically to return the Hash value for a given language key if the key exists in the Hash. If it doesn't, then return the value of the `'english'` key instead. Implicit in the exercise is to understand the various types of improper inputs that would fail to find a matching key; the solution below addresses most of them, and will work even if your Ruby has frozen strings enabled.

### A Working Solution

There are lots of ways to do this, but here's a simple example that will handle invalid keys, `nil` as a language argument, and abstract away capitalization as a potential issue.

```rb
DEFAULT_LANG = 'english'
TRANSLATIONS = { 
    'english'    => 'Welcome',
    'czech'      => 'Vitejte',
    'danish'     => 'Velkomst',
    'dutch'      => 'Welkom',
    'estonian'   => 'Tere tulemast',
    'finnish'    => 'Tervetuloa',
    'flemish'    => 'Welgekomen',
    'french'     => 'Bienvenue',
    'german'     => 'Willkommen',
    'irish'      => 'Failte',
    'italian'    => 'Benvenuto',
    'latvian'    => 'Gaidits',
    'lithuanian' => 'Laukiamas',
    'polish'     => 'Witamy',
    'spanish'    => 'Bienvenido',
    'swedish'    => 'Valkommen',
    'welsh'      => 'Croeso'
}

# Return a translation of "Welcome" into the language
# passed as an argument.
#
# @param language [String, #to_s] any object that can
#   be coerced into a String, and therefore to 
#   String#downcase
# @return [String] a translation of "Welcome" or the
#   string-literal +Welcome+ if no translation found
def greet language
  language = language.to_s.downcase
  TRANSLATIONS.fetch language, TRANSLATIONS[DEFAULT_LANG]
end

# Everything in the following Array of examples except
# +Spanish+ should return the Hash value for +english+.                                                                                               
['Spanish', 'Español', 123, nil].map { greet(_1) }
```

This will correctly return:

> `#=> ["Bienvenido", "Welcome", "Welcome", "Welcome"]`

because only `Spanish` (when lower-cased) will match any of the keys currently defined in the *TRANSLATIONS* Hash. All the rest will use the default value defined for the exercise.

### Test Results

Since there are some RSpec tests included with the linked question:

```rb
describe "Welcome! Translation" do
  it "should translate input" do
    Test.assert_equals(greet('english'), 'Welcome', "It didn't work out this time, keep trying!");
    Test.assert_equals(greet('dutch'), 'Welkom', "It didn't work out this time, keep trying!");
    Test.assert_equals(greet('IP_ADDRESS_INVALID'), 'Welcome', "It didn't work out this time, keep trying!")
  end
end
```

The code provided not only passes the provided tests, but it also passes a number of other edge cases not defined in the unit tests. When run against the defined tests, the code above passes cleanly:

[image: passing unit tests]

If this is homework, then you might want to create additional tests to cover all the various edge cases. You might also choose to refactor to less idiomatic code if you want more explanatory variables, more explicit intermediate conversions, or more explicit key handling. The point of good code is to be readable, so be as explicit in your code and as thorough in your tests as you need to be in order to make debugging easier.